# Blank spaces are still being added to the file

Tags: whitespace

When I am adding information to the file it does that all and well. It error checks the fields but at the end, adds blank spaces to the file.
This also happens if the fields are kept blank.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        If Char.IsNumber(txtStudentID.Text) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Text cannot include letters or be clear, fill in  correctly before proceeding",
                            "User Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            txtStudentID.Clear()
            txtStudentID.Focus()
        Else
            OneMember.StudentID = txtStudentID.Text
        End If

        Char.IsLetter(txtName.Name)
        If Char.IsLetter(txtName.Text) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Text cannot include number or be clear, fill in  correctly before proceeding",
                            "User Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            txtName.Clear()
            txtName.Focus()
        Else
            'OneMember.NameOfStudent = txtName.Text
        End If



        Char.IsLetter(txtLesson.Name)

        If Char.IsLetter(txtLesson.Text) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Text cannot include number or be clear, fill in  correctly before proceeding",
                            "User Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            txtLesson.Clear()
            txtLesson.Focus()
        Else
            'OneMember.Lesson = txtLesson.Text
        End If


        Char.IsNumber(txtPayed.Text)

        If Char.IsNumber(txtPayed.Text) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Text cannot include letters or be clear, fill in  correctly before proceeding",
                            "User Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            txtPayed.Clear()
            txtPayed.Focus()
        Else
            OneMember.AmountPayed = txtPayed.Text
        End If

        OneMember.NameOfStudent = txtName.Text
        OneMember.Lesson = txtLesson.Text
        OneMember.DOl = txtDate.Text
        OneMember.TOL = txtTime.Text
        FileOpen(1, AddLesson, OpenMode.Random, , , Len(OneMember))
        NumberOfRecords = LOF(1) / Len(OneMember)
        FilePut(1, OneMember, NumberOfRecords + 1)
        FileClose()
        NumberOfRecords = NumberOfRecords + 1
        txtStudentID.Clear()
        txtName.Clear()
        txtDate.Clear()
        txtTime.Clear()
        txtLesson.Clear()
        txtPayed.Clear()
        MsgBox(" Student added to file")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Tag the question with the programming languages used to get more people to see it.

Comment: Also, please take a good look at your post. Does it look like it was supposed to? (I hope not.) There is markdown help available when you [edit] your question. As a new member, you probably should check out the [Tour].